# Accepting values of dynamically created HTML input textboxes in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I want to generate a column full of input text boxes inside a table.

At present, i generate my table dynamically from C# through StringBuilder.

```
sb.Append("<tr><td>" + item[0].ToString() + "</td><td>" + item[1].ToString() + 
    "</td><td>" + item[2].ToString() + "</td><td>" + item.GetString(3) + "</td><td>" + 
    item.GetDecimal(4) + "</td><td>"+ "<input type=\"text\" class=\"input-mini\" 
    columns=\"1\" name=\"ids\" ID= 'textbox" + i + "' /></td></tr>");
```

I understand that i can get the input values via `jquery` and pass it to `C#` method, but is there a more simpler way to achieve the same?

EDIT: To show Form Handling

```
for (int element = 0; element <= totalelements; j++)
{
    toList.Add(Request.Form["'textbox" + element + "'"]);
}
```

.aspx page (This button's visibility is toggled by a div)

```
<asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn" Height="27px" Width="190px" OnClick="doSomething" ID="do" Text="Send" />
```

Comment: ajax using Jquery  is the simplest way...

Comment: @musefan I mean, posting the values back and retrieving at the server. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @Naraen: How are you posting? Form post, or AJAX post? You should include either you server side POST handling code, or your javascript AJAX code

Answer (score 2):

If you want to handle dynamic textboxes on the server side after a form post then firstly you need to change your HTML to use unique `name` values, for example:

```
name='textbox0'
```

ID attributes will not be used when a form is submitted.

---

Then, server side you can access the elements using `Request.Form["elementName"]`. If you know the number of dynamic elements you have, then do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++)
{
    string textValue = Request.Form["textbox" + i].ToString();
    //do something with text value
}
```

If you don't know the number of elements, you can do it like this:

```
int i = 0;
while(true)
{
    var textBox = Request.Form["textbox" + i];
    if(textBox == null)//ran out of textbox elements to process
        break;

    string textValue = textBox.ToString();
    //do something with text value

    i++;
}
```